# Finding a recurrence relation for a sequence not containing $0$ in the digits. Also showing $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n \dfrac{1}{a_k} < 90$

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations

Let $1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,11,12,\ldots$ be the sequence of all positive integers which do not contain the digit zero. Write $\{a_n\}$ for this sequence. By comparing with a geometric series, show that $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n \dfrac{1}{a_k} < 90$.

My attempts:

I could not attempt the first part of the question to find a formula for generalising $\{a_n\}$ but for the second part, I tried,

$$\sum_n \dfrac{1}{a_n}<1+\dfrac12+\dfrac12+\dfrac14+\dfrac14+\dfrac14+\dfrac14+\ldots$$

but could not get anything worth of mention. Please help.

Comment: For the inequality: How many $a_k$ are there with exactly $d$ digits?

Comment: This is a [Kempner series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kempner_series). See [also](http://eprints.maths.ox.ac.uk/1106/1/NA-06-17.pdf).

Comment: @DanielFischer I suppose that is a hint?

Comment: @Hawk It is at least intended to be one.

Comment: @DanielFischer unfortunately, I do not get it... :(

Comment: But do you know the answer?

Comment: @DanielFischer when $d$ is specified, I think I can tell how many $a_k$...but not the generalised form.

Comment: There are exactly $9$ such $a_k$ with exactly one digit. For each of these, $1/a_k<1$. There are exactly $9^2$ such $a_k$ with exactly two digits. For each of these, $1/a_k<1/10$. ...

Comment: @DavidMitra yes, you are correct... that is brilliant...now I can do the inequality, but how to find the generalised form?

Comment: @DanielFischer after DavidMitra's comment, I understand, what you meant to say...and what was I thinking?